# My VScode Theme always reverts to default dark+ on opening

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my settings.json I have it listed that I want my default theme to be Monokai, but whenever I open Vscode from my windows menu, it starts up with Default Dark+. I switch the theme literally whenever I use vscode and its just annoying. I know this is probably an easy fix but I'm extremely frustrated.

```
     "settings": {
            "git.ignoreLimitWarning": true,
            "workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai",
            "window.zoomLevel": 0.4,
            "editor.fontSize": 16,
            "editor.formatOnSave": true,
            "editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 30

    },
```

Comment: Just in case check to make sure there is no ""workbench.colorTheme" in workspace settings (I assume that is your User Settings above).

Comment: Ahhh thank you. I wasnt understanding that workspace settings were the current settings and user settings are your settings that you set. Thanks alot Mark

Comment: Actually, you can set both.  Workspace settings are more "specific" and will override the User settings.  The user settings will apply to all your projects/workspaces unless overridden by the workspace settings.  That is why I asked if you has a workbench.colorTheme setting which would override your User Settings.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the answer to this one: **an extension named reageyao.biosyntax** was overwriting the value in my settings.json every time I tried to run it.

If you don't have that one installed, or disabling it doesn't fix the problem, you may be able to fix it by running extension bisect. Here's how:

Press cmd + shift + p (or ctrl + shift + p if you're on Windows) while in Visual Studio Code to run a command, then type "Start Extension Bisect". Each time that program runs, it will turn off half of the remaining extensions and ask you if the problem has been fixed.

After every iteration, try editing the `workbench.colorTheme` value in settings.json to see if it has been fixed. You should be able to figure out which extension is causing the issue.

Also, here's [a related thread](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/137635) I found on GitHub which might help you.